# Python(using IDLE): Module Not Found Error: No module named 'page'

Tags: python, selenium

I am learning Selenium-python and when I run the example in the index 6.1 Test case: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html. An error displays "Python: Module Not Found Error: No module named 'page'". I have installed pip selenium, and I try to run it on Python 2.7 and Python 3.6, but the same error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you create the file 'page.py' ?

Comment: Oh, thanks @MauriceMeyer, I see at the next index and 'page.py' is at there. The tutorial should let the imported page above. At first I thought 'page.py' is a library in pip package. Oh men!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pip to install the library `page`.
If you ever get a module not found error go on Google and opening se the search term `pip install modulename`. Select the search result from PyPi and it will have a box you can copy from. Open up command prompt and type what PyPi says and it will add the module.

If in the future you use PyPharm then use the terminal tab at the bottom instead of command prompt.

Hopefully explaining the steps instead of just saying what to put in command prompt will help all module not found errors you may have in the future